# Rails 4.2.0 : Display message when collection is empty

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I tried with this in my index.html.erb but it didn't work.

```
<%= render(@xvaziris) ||  'No records' %>
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

        <div class="table-responsive myTable">

            <table id = "kola" class="table listing text-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="tr-head">
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Amount</td>
                        <td>Discount</td>
                        <td>Paid</td>
                        <td>Balance</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <a href="#" class="toggle-formed" style="float: right;" ><strong>Search</strong></a>

                <div id="sample">

                    <%= form_tag xvaziris_path, remote: true, method: :get, class: "form-group", role: "search" do %>
                    <p>
                        <center><%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search for.....", autofocus: true, class: "form-control-search" %>
                            <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-md btn-primary" %></center>
                        </p>
                        <% end %><br>
                    </div>


                    <tbody>              
                        <%= render(@xvaziris) ||  'No records' %>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

index.js.erb

```
<% @balance = 0 %> 
$('#kola tbody').empty(); 
<% @xvaziris.each do |xvaziri| %> 
$('#kola tbody').append("<%= j render xvaziri %>"); 
<% end %>
```

Do I need to wrap it somewhere in index.js.erb in order to function.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might want something like this:

```
<% if @xvaziris.empty? %>
  <em>No records</em>
<% else %>
  <%= render(@xvaziris) %>
<% end %>
```

Or another, shorter, but less readable way:

```
<%= @xvaziris.present? ? render(@xvaziris) : "No Records" %>
```

I personally prefer the first solution

So you're asking why your solution does not work..
It's because `render` returns a string. (Which in your case is empty)

The `||` operator is like a short if/else:
let's say you have a value which is nil, then you do this:

```
value = nil
value || 1 # => will return 1
```

now the if/else way:

```
value = nil
result = if value
           value
         else
           1
         end
result # => will return 1
```

Now in your case:

```
value = render(...) # => "" (empty string)
value || "something else" # => "" (empty string)
```

this is because an empty string **does not** return false

to check if a value is true or false you can use double negotiation (`!!` operator) it's just a way to cast an object to a boolean.

```
empty_string = ""
!!empty_string # => true

!!nil # => false
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Do I need to wrap anything in index.js.erb file? As I am retrieving data from that file.

Comment: what are you doing with your index.js.erb file?

I think this is never loaded.

Comment: Thanks.But I am rendering the partial from there as I am using Ajax way.

Comment: Please make it little bit clear "If you then take that in an if (in your ||)"

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen

Can you explain me, where your index.js.erb is loaded?

To your second question:
I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is located under xvaziris folder i.e., xvaziris/index.js.erb

Comment: It is located under xvaziris folder i.e., xvaziris/index.js.erb

Answer (score 0):

After I changed the index.js.erb with if else condition in the following manner, I got it working.

index.js.erb

```
<% @balance = 0 %>
$('#kola tbody').empty();

<% if @xvaziris.empty? %>
$('#kola tr').remove();
$('#kola tbody').append("No Results Found For Your Search...");
$("#kola tbody").css({"background-color": "white", "font-size": "100%", "font-weight": "900"}); 
<% else %>
<% @xvaziris.each do |xvaziri| %>
$('#kola tbody').append("<%= j render xvaziri %>");
<% end %>
<% end %>
```